# Lex/Yacc: Code for tokenizing and parsing C source file

Tags: yacc, lex

right now, I am studying the code below
http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html

```
{L}{A}*                             { return check_type(); }

{HP}{H}+{IS}?                       { return I_CONSTANT; }
{NZ}{D}*{IS}?                       { return I_CONSTANT; }
"0"{O}*{IS}?                        { return I_CONSTANT; }
{CP}?"'"([^'\\\n]|{ES})+"'"         { return I_CONSTANT; }

{D}+{E}{FS}?                        { return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}*"."{D}+{E}?{FS}?                { return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}+"."{E}?{FS}?                    { return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+{P}{FS}?                    { return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}*"."{H}+{P}{FS}?             { return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+"."{P}{FS}?                 { return F_CONSTANT; }

({SP}?\"([^"\\\n]|{ES})*\"{WS}*)+   { return STRING_LITERAL; }
```

I want to ask that what is the meaning of this part of the code? and how does it concern with Yacc? The Yacc code is http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html

Comment: Without knowing what e.g. `L` and `A` etc is, we can't help you. We can *guess* that it's about tokenizing numeric and string literals (guessing from the returned symbols). How Lex and Yacc work together is to broad here on Stack Overflow, but there are many tutorials and guides on Lex and Yacc (or variants) all over the Internet.

Comment: The page you link to is clearly entitled "lex specification", and that is what it is. In other words, it has nothing to do with yacc adide from also being part of the parsing pipeline.